# Peticiones Ajax con valores de parámetros null en la página de destino

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Tras actualizar Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 a la versión 16.11.11 me he encontrado el problema de que al realizar una petición Ajax pasando una cadena de consulta con uno o más parámetros el valor de esos parámetros cuando se carga la página del servidor que recibe la petición es siempre **null**. En envío Ajax se efectúa puesto que puedo interrumpir el código en la página de destino y ver que el dato recibido es **null**. Supongo que el problema está en la cadena de consulta que se envía. El mismo código en las mismas funciones Javascript ha funcionado hasta ahora. Debe ser algún cambio introducido en la versión 16.11.11 el que está provocando este comportamiento.

La cadena de consulta que paso está verificada y comprobada, ya que envía valores en cada uno de sus parámetros (comprobado en el cliente inmediatamente antes de la petición Ajax). Este comportamiento se da en todas las páginas del proyecto.

La petición se hace desde el cliente así:

```
 xhttp.open("POST", "Alumnos.aspx", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(cadconsulta);
```

Donde *Alumnos.aspx* es la página que recibirá la petición; *true*, indica que el envío es asíncrono.
*cadconsulta* es una variable de cadena de texto que contiene la cadena de consulta en la forma "*página.aspx?parámetro1=valor1&parámetro2=valor2...etc*".

Los valores en la página que recibe la petición los obtengo en el evento **Load** de la página así:

```
string valordelparametro = Request["nombredelparametro"];
```

Hasta esta actualización esta forma de proceder me ha funcionado perfectamente. ¿Ha habido algún cambio respecto a Ajax en la versión 16.11.11? ¿Hay que configurar algo para usar Ajax? No recuerdo haber tenido que configurar nada específico para Ajax anteriormente.

Saludos

Comment: En la consola del navegador recibes algun mensaje de error? El cors suele ser un problema habitual

Comment: No recibo ningún error. La página no se llega a visualizar en el navegador porque la utilizo para recibir peticiones, procesar la información y responder a cada una de diferentes formas. Puedo ir paso a paso y ver que el valor de la variable es null después de haber pasado por request. He probado a usar el encodeURI y el encodeURIcomponent para evitar cualquier problema de la cadena, pero siempre se devuelve null.

Comment: Has probado a hacer la misma peticion o parecida desde postman o thunderclient?

Comment: No. Lo voy a intentar.

Comment: Ayer estube peleando con .net core 6. Desde el navegador obtenia error y desde thunder iba correcto. Era un problema de cors. Y como consejo porque no usas fetch o axios, es mas sintetico

Comment: Pero en este momento estoy trabajando en local. Se puede también hacer la prueba con postman con una URL local?

Comment: Estaba revisando xhttp en mdn y seguro tu problema es que no es una peticion https. Las ignora. Fetch si permite locales

Comment: Ya. Es que esta forma ha funcionado perfectamente en todas las páginas del proyecto.

Comment: A  nivel local nunca necesité indicar nada para que sea https. Cuando subo todo al servidor allí si está todo bajo https. Esta forma de hacer las peticiones Ajax las llevo usando desde tiempo y siempre me han funcionado en local y después en online con https.

Comment: Ya hice la petición en remoto con https y postman. No arroja arrores. Realmente no tengo más información que con la depuración paso a paso, con la que puedo ver el valor null. Hay un problema que hace que la cadena de consulta no se pueda recibir o leer en el servidor.

Comment: Solucionado! Con la nueva actualización separar la página y la cadena de consulta no funciona. Pongo en una respuesta la solución. Muchas gracias Hernán por contestar. He conocido el postman, que me parece buena herramienta.

Answer (score 1):

La razón del problema esta en que con la nueva actualización 16.11.11 de VS 2019 no se acepta separar la página *destino* y la *cadena de consulta* entre los métodos **open** y **send**. Deben ir juntas como una sola cadena en el parámetro **url** del método **open**. De la siguiente forma:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "Alumnos.aspx?" + cadconsulta, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send();
```

Ahora el método **send** no lleva ningún argumento y la variable *cadconsulta* está concatenada después de *Alumnos.aspx?*. De esta forma funciona correctamente.